# FPDF - download file via Javascript without saving on server

Tags: javascript, php, fpdf

I would like to save generated pdf file on user browser but sending a file directly to a browser, not using a temporary file.
The PHP script needs some info from JS, so I send it to a PHP script (with FPDF) using the POST.
I use also interval for making some things after it downloads.
For this test script, I wanted to make all used functionality. But only downloading PDF doesn't work.
PDF document in Firefox is opening but with 3 blanc pages.
On Chrome it opens a new blanc window.

Javascript(HTML):

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <script>
                var clr_timersControl = new Array();
                clr_timersControl['pdfGenerate'] = 0;
                var i = 0;
                var formData = new FormData();

                var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                formData.append('name', name);

                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if(xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200) {
                        var pdf = xmlHttp.responseText;        

                        var batch = window.open(
                            'data:application/pdf,'+encodeURIComponent(pdf),
                            'Batch Print',
                            'width=600,height=600,location=_newtab'
                         );
                        clr_timersControl['pdfGenerate'] = 1;
                    }
                }
                xmlHttp.open('post', 'test2.php'); 
                xmlHttp.send(formData);

                var interval = setInterval(function(){
                    console.log(i++);
                    if ( window.clr_timersControl['pdfGenerate'] === 1) {
                        //do something after download pdf file
                        clearInterval(interval);
                    }
                }, 200);
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            Text text.
        </body>
    </html>
```

PHP script:

```
<?php
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='downloaded.pdf'");

require('./clr_php/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{

function Header()
{
    $this->Image('./clr_data/nemoxx/logo.jpg',10,6,30);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    $this->Cell(80);
    $this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');
    $this->Ln(20);
}

function Footer()
{
    $this->SetY(-15);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}
}

$pdf = new PDF('L','mm','A4');
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++) {
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,'Printing line number '.$i,0,1);
}

header('Content-Length: '.strlen($pdf));
$pdf->Output('','I');
exit();
```

Comment: Hi @arrowman Did you find out how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> **8. I use jQuery to generate the PDF but it doesn't show.**
>
> Don't use an AJAX request to retrieve the PDF.
>
> http://www.fpdf.org/en/FAQ.php

You could save the file to the server and return the URL of the PDF?

Comment: No, I can't save file on the server. It is problem I know.